# Traceback: in in greet NameError:

Tags: python, variables, global

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?
I get this message:

```
Traceback: in in greet NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
```

From this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greet(self, other_name):
        return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, name)
```

Comment: Well, where do you think is the `name` in `greet()` coming from?

Comment: Why are you trying to redefine `other_name`? Get rid of the first line of `greet`, and replace `.format(other_name, name)` with `.format(other_name, self.name)` to get the data you need.

Answer (score 3):

`name` is out of scope in the greet function. You need to use `self.name` instead. e.g.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greet(self, other_name):
        self.other_name = other_name
        return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, self.name)
```

You can verify that it works

```
>>> mitch = Person('mitch')
>>> mitch.greet('mitchell') # prints 'Hi mitchell, my name is mitch'
>>> mitch.name # prints 'mitch'
>>> mitch.other_name # prints 'mitchell'
```

Answer (score 0):

`name` is an instance attribute of class `Person`.  Meaning, you need to prefix it with `self.` to access its value:

```
return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, self.name)
#                                                  ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thx very much, but shouldn t be name declares as a global variable? Why can i access it with self.?

Comment: @OkanAlbayrak - No, `name` is not a global.  `name` was an argument that was passed to `Person.__init__` and then made an instance attribute via `self.name = name`.  Its value is accessible through `self` because `self` is a reference to the class instance itself.